# Desktop App Converter CommandNotFoundException

Tags: windows-10, desktop-app-converter

I have been using Desktop App Converter, until I have the above Exception.

It starts with 'The term  'DesktopAppConverter.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.'

Even when I uninstall and then re-install it, it's the same.

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the packages with the new [free Express edition from Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html), developed in partnership with Microsoft, its purpose is to complement the Desktop App Converter.

It has a GUI that allows for advanced customization of the APPX packages, without requiring you to have knowledge about the internals package schemas.

If you have any questions about it, let me know, would love to help.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team that builds Advanced Installer.*